# impossible to use webview with thread javafx service

Tags: java, javafx

I wrote a little program using javafx threads, but my UI remained frozen because he could not instantiate a webview that I use after. here is a part of my code :

```
 // create thread
    final Service<AnchorPane>  myService = new Service<AnchorPane>() {
            @Override
                protected Task<AnchorPane> createTask() {
                    return new Task<AnchorPane>() {
                       @Override
                       protected AnchorPane call() throws Exception
                        {
                            loader = new FXMLLoader();
                            Controller controller = new Controller(getCmpName());
                            loader.setController(controller);
                             loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Layout.fxml"));   
                            controller.setApp(app);                                                             
                            AnchorPane bs = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
                            return bs;
                        }

                    };
                }

           };//end create service
          myService.stateProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> observableValue, Worker.State oldValue, Worker.State newValue) ->
           {
                  switch (newValue) {
                                  case FAILED:
                                  case CANCELLED:
                                  case RUNNING:                                                     
                                  case SUCCEEDED:                                                             
                                  app.getContainer().setCenter(myService.getValue());
                                   break;
                                  }
              });
                 // launch thread
               bsService.start();
```

and  in my controller :

```
private void initialize() {
        ....
     webViewChart = new WebView();//bug UI FROZE
     webEngine = webViewChart.getEngine();
     URL test = getClass().getResource("chart3.html");
     webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
     new ChangeListener<State>(){
     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov, State oldState, State newState) {
          if(newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED){
               JSObject window = (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript("window");
               window.setMember("app", new JavaApplication());
               webEngine.executeScript("displayGraph()" );
              }
           }
          });  
             webEngine.load(test.toExternalForm());
             webViewChart.setPrefSize(450, 250);
             chart.getChildren().add(webViewChart);
    }
```

Comment: Like nearly all UI frameworks, JavaFX is single threaded.  All Node constructors and methods must be called on the JavaFX application thread.  Building a UI tree in a separate thread won’t provide any benefit anyway, since the time to do it is most likely measurable in milliseconds.

Comment: my concern here is to avoid that the UI is blocked by waiting for data that's why I wanted to use a thread.

Comment: Then you probably want to only load the data in a Service.  Your UI code should bind the Service’s value (which should be data, not JavaFX Nodes) to the UI components’ properties.

Comment: Then you probably want to load only the data into a service. Your UI code must bind the value of the service (which should be data, not JavaFX nodes) to the properties of the UI components.
Actually it is the case, The data come after. The problem here is that I can not even instantiate the webview before trying to pass him the data.